# Help understanding this code: public Opportunity[] relatedApp {get;set;}

Tags: apex

can you help me with a question?
I'm studying some code here and I came across this line:

```
public Opportunity[] relatedApp {get;set;}
```

what is happening on that line?
I mean, why did the programmer use the characters `[]`
later the code continues with:

```
public List<Opportunity> getAppends1(){
        if(relatedApp != null && relatedApp.size()>0)
            return relatedApp;

        try{
//            relatedApp = aSiteUtils.queryResults4(Opportunity.SObjectType, null,'AccountId = :v1', activeAccount.Id, 'RecordType.DeveloperName = :v2', 'AnexoI', 'Safra__c = :v3',activeSession.Safra__c, 'Marca__c = :v4', activeSession.Marca__c);
            relatedApp = aAppManager.getAnexos1(activeAccount.Id, safraActual, activeSession.Marca__c);

            if(relatedApp.size()>0)
                recId=relatedApp[0].Id;

            setActiveApp1();
        
            return relatedApp;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,e.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I'm having trouble understanding what's being done, who can help I appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<X>` and `X[]` are synonyms. They serve the exact same purpose, to declare a `List` (an ordered collection) of items. You can generally use these interchangeably, except for some rare cases. For example, you can write `List<X[]>` to mean `List<List<X>>`, but you cannot write `X[][]` to mean the same thing. I personally prefer the `[]` when I can, given my significantly longer experience with classic languages like C and C++ that had this notation as their only option before `std::array` and other options were introduced.

This code, `getAppends1`, is a lazy-loading function. First, it checks if the results (`relatedApp`) have already been queried, and if so, returns that. Otherwise, it queries some records, and stores those in the variable. It then selects the first item in the list if any records are present, and sets the active app. Finally, it returns the list.

It's worth noting that the try-catch is probably not necessary here, or at least, it's undocumented. This code is also missing `{}` for the if statement, which isn't required, but is in violation of [best practices](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_codestyle.html#ifstmtsmustusebraces). In addition, the first statement can be rewritten using the new [Safe Navigation Operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm):

```
if(relatedApp?.size()>0) { // ...
```

Finally, the `{ get; set; }` just means to use the "default getter and setter." You'll find this is necessary for `@AuraEnabled` properties and Visualforce variables that you want to display on a Visualforce page. If you don't need `relatedApp` for either of these purposes, you can just use:

```
public Opportunity[] relatedApp;
```

Comment: Thank you fou you explanation, helped me a lot! @sfdcfox